# Error when I call a method within a python class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

When I run the code below, I get a NameError that *bbo* is not defined.

```
from typing import Tuple
import requests
import os

class Level:

    __slots__ = ['price', 'amount']

    def __init__(self, price: float, amount: float):
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount

    def initialize(trading_pair: str):
        pass

    def bbo(trading_pair: str) -> Tuple:
        endpt = "https://api.binance.com"
        api = "/api/v3/depth"
        response = requests.get(endpt + api + trading_pair)
        bids_str, asks_str = response.json()["bids"], response.json()["asks"]
        bids = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in bids_str]
        asks = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in asks_str]
        return (Level(max(bids)[0],max(bids)[1]), Level(min(asks)[0],min(asks)[1]))

    def main(trading_pair: str):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            bb, ba = bbo(trading_pair)
            print(f"Best Bid: {bb.amount}@{bb.price}  Best Ask: {ba.amount}@{ba.price}")

    if __name__=='__main__':
        trading_pair = os.getenv("TRADING_PAIR", "BTCUSDT")
        initialize(trading_pair)
        main(trading_pair)
```

When I added *self* to main()

```
def main(self, trading_pair: str):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            bb, ba = self.bbo(trading_pair)
            print(f"Best Bid: {bb.amount}@{bb.price}  Best Ask: {ba.amount}@{ba.price}")
```

I got a TypeError saying main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trading_pair'. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to add the ```self``` as the first parameter in your methods.

Comment: when I do that, i get the TypeError missing 1 required positional argument: 'traiding_pair' for all of my methods

Comment: I don't mean to the ```main``` function; but to the methods within your ```Level``` class.  That said,  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.   I think one option you can do is make ```def bbo(...)``` as a static method.

Comment: What's the purpose of the ```initialize(trading_pair)``` call for?

Comment: currently the initialize method does nothing. im keeping it in reserve just in case i need to initialize something. when I run this script on the terminal, it works perfectly up until the bbo() call within the main() method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that you're having, even if you've included
the `self` parameter in your methods.

Firstly, your `__main__` call:

```
    trading_pair = os.getenv("TRADING_PAIR", "BTCUSDT")
    initialize(trading_pair)
    main(trading_pair)
```

This isn't going to work since `initialize` is supposed to be a method within the `Level` class.  So you will get an undeclared variable in `initialize`.  But since it doesn't do anything right now, I'm only guessing you're going to use it to do some initializing.  Will get to this later.

The main method `bbo` seems to be the (for lack of a better word) actual initializer, so I'll concentrate on that.

Here's my take on your code:

```
from typing import Tuple
import requests
import os
import time

class Level:

    __slots__ = ['price', 'amount']

    def __init__(self, price: float, amount: float):
        self.price = price
        self.amount = amount

    def initialize(self, trading_pair: str):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def bbo(trading_pair: str) -> Tuple:
        endpt = "https://api.binance.com"
        api = "/api/v3/depth"
        response = requests.get(endpt + api + trading_pair)
        bids_str, asks_str = response.json()["bids"], response.json()["asks"]
        bids = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in bids_str]
        asks = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in asks_str]
        return (Level(max(bids)[0],max(bids)[1]), 
                Level(min(asks)[0],min(asks)[1]))


def main(trading_pair: str):
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        bb, ba = Level.bbo(trading_pair)
        print(f"Best Bid: {bb.amount}@{bb.price}  Best Ask: {ba.amount}@{ba.price}")

if __name__=='__main__':
    trading_pair = os.getenv("TRADING_PAIR", "BTCUSDT")
    main(trading_pair)
```

Your `initialize` method does nothing but if it's just a
place holder for future use, I'll just keep it at that.  However,
you need to bear in mind that if you do need to use it,
you will need to place it where you've already instantiated
the `Level` class.  Something along the lines of (but
not exactly, since I don't know what the `initialize`
will do):

```
    @staticmethod
    def bbo(self, trading_pair: str) -> Tuple:
        endpt = "https://api.binance.com"
        api = "/api/v3/depth"
        response = requests.get(endpt + api + trading_pair)
        bids_str, asks_str = response.json()["bids"], response.json()["asks"]
        bids = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in bids_str]
        asks = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in asks_str]
        bid_level = Level(max(bids)[0],max(bids)[1])
        ask_level = Level(min(asks)[0],min(asks)[1])
        bid_level.initialize(trading_pair)
        ask_level.initialize(trading_pair)
        return (bid_level,  ask_level)
```

That said, you'll also need to include error checking
just in case the response.json() ends up being invalid,
or the response being invalid. (again, just a suggestion).

I've tested the code, but I'm getting a 404 error, so I"m
not sure if the url is correct or I'm missing some
credentials.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.  I'm not getting that error.

Comment: Ive finally gotten it to work. Thank you very much @ewong.